# how to find how many customers accessed application daily on date basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design

Hi I have a mobile application in that MobApp, customer can see the information about

money,news,forecast,advice in that i need to find out the count for how many times customers visited

money,news,forecast,advice separately on daily basis based on date.

The log table consists of columns like

```
id  user_key  url_accessed   parameters           timestamp 
.. .........  ............   ..........          ............
1   sdhbhjbh  /user/money  mobile_no=9999999  2015-01-08 13:06:33
2   cnbjknjk  /user/news   user_key=534d2135  2014-09-06 26:02:25
```

Here I have to find how many times user accessed the url daily on date basis and count for accessing

the url of money,news,forecast,advice

Here  I am using SQL Server with Pentaho data integration

Please help in this issue

Comment: Looks like `Group by` with `count` should work. Please show some effort. It is really basic stuff in Sql

Comment: do you want number of unique users or just number of users?

Comment: @SRI updated answer to make the count unique

Comment: @Rishu For above issue i have to create separate new_table for url_accessed with columns money,news,weather,forecast. Here, i need to populate the data from log_table to new_table where the columns money,news,weather,forecast in this columns the data has to be count of money,count of news and for all columns using pentaho data integration. How can i do this, help me in this task

Comment: @SRI can you start a different question thread on this since the comment question seems a bit different than the one you just have asked in comment above!!.. hope you understand :)

Answer (score 2):

Presumably, users can access the app more than once in a day.  If so, you want `count(distinct)`:

```
select cast(timestamp as date) as thedate, count(distinct user_key)
from log l
group by cast(timestamp as date)
order by thedate;
```

Comment: here it is showing 2 columns (thedate count(distinct user_key) like 2014-04-06 (3),2014-04-07 (5),2014-04-08 (13) it means (3),(5),(13) are the visits of url by user

Answer (score 1):

Using `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` it counts the unique number of users that have accessed each URL.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT user_key), url_accessed
FROM logtable
GROUP BY url_accessed
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_key) user_key,
  url_accessed,
  CAST(timestamp as date) datestamp
FROM 
  yourtable
WHERE 
  url in ('/user/money', '/user/news', '/user/forecast', '/user/advice')
GROUP BY 
  url_accessed,
  CAST(timestamp as date)
ORDER BY 
  CAST(timestamp as date)
```