# To find out how many users accessed url every day based on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

Hi I have a mobile application in that MobApp, customer can see the information about

money,news,forecast,advice and can download the app in that case i need to find out the count for how

many times customers visited money,news,forecast,advice and through which ref code customer

downloaded app separately on daily basis or download date

The log table consists of columns like

id  user_key  url_accessed   parameters           timestamp 
.. .........  ............   ..........          ............

1   sdhbhjbh  /user/money  mobile_no=9999999  2015-01-08 13:06:33

2   cnbjknjk  /user/news   user_key=534d2135  2014-09-06 26:02:25

3   l;mjl;k;  /download    ref=abcd           2014-10-22 07:37:57

Here I have to find how many times user accessed the url daily on date basis and count for accessing

the url of money,news,forecast,advisory,download

Here I am using SQL Server with Pentaho data integration

For above issue i have to create separate new_table for url_accessed with columns

money,news,weather,forecast,download. Here, i need to populate the data from log_table to new_table

where the columns money,news,weather,forecast,download are in this columns the data has to come count

for money,count for news and for all columns

using pentaho data integration. How can i do this, help me in this task

Answer (score 0):

This might helps you

```
Select user,URL,count(URL)
from table
where date=getdate() 
group by URL,user
```

Comment: above u have given query for count for columns that is fine but at the same time i mentioned in my question that i need to populate count data to specified columns as well and that data has to go another table in another table the column names are money,news,weather,advisory,download

Answer (score 0):

Using PDI, you can try **first** of all to use the sql queries(as mentioned above and in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902282/how-to-find-how-many-customers-accessed-application-daily-on-date-basis?noredirect=1#comment44269204_27902282)) to get the distinct count of the users.

[image]

**Secondly**, you need to find out from the url, what are the columns that are getting accessed. For e.g.; if an user has accessed "/user/money" then his tab-access would be "money". The sum count of your data in the new-table need to be in this table.

**Third**, use "Memory Group By" step to get the total sum count of the tab's accessed. Check the image below. *[Note: i have only used minimal parameter, u can use users as another condition]*

**Fourth**, Load this data into some staging table and **Finally** in a separate transformation, query this staging table *(use case statements)* and load the data as per your required format/table.

I have given a very basic sample in [here](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/41b01516cdb20df1e00e). Please check it out.

Hoping this will help you out :)

[image]

Comment: In Modified Java Script Value i don't have much knowledge of xml, in place of ID_BATCH,CHANNEL_ID what have to mention

Comment: @SRI copy the xml code and save it using the .ktr extension. Then open it in PDI. u can see the code. :) Use notepad++ or some editor.. and i have used Pentaho 5.0.0 version

Comment: in above diagram in place of tab_accessed i have to get money,forecast,news as columns for that where can i make changes

Comment: @SRI read the fourth and final step in the solutions. Load the tab_accessed data into a seperate staging table and then sql the data in the next transformation. I have told you to create a separate ktr for this.